# Adding a catalog to XSLT Saxon s9api in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, s9api

I have the following code which takes XML as input and produces a bunch of other files as output.

```
   public void transformXml(InputStream inputFileStream, Path outputDir) {

    try {
      Resource resource = resourceLoader
          .getResource("classpath:demo.xslt");

      LOGGER.info("Creating output XMLs and Assessment Report in {}", outputDir);
      final File outputFile = new File(outputDir.toString());

      final Processor processor = getSaxonProcessor();
      XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
      XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(resource.getFile()));
      Xslt30Transformer transformer = stylesheet.load30();

      Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(outputFile);
      out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
      transformer.transform(new StreamSource(inputFileStream), out);
      LOGGER.debug("Generated DTD XMLs and Assessment Report successfully in {}", outputDir);
    } catch (SaxonApiException e) {
      throw new XmlTransformationException("Error occured during transformation", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new XmlTransformationException("Error occured during loading XSLT file", e);
    }
  }

  private Processor getSaxonProcessor() {
    final Configuration configuration = Configuration.newConfiguration();
    configuration.disableLicensing();
    Processor processor = new Processor(configuration);
    return processor;
  }
```

The XML input contains a DOCTYPE tag which resolves to a DTD that is not available to me. Hence why I am wanting to use a catalog to point it to a dummy DTD which is on my classpath.
I am struggling to find a way to this. Most examples that I find out there, are not using the s9api implementation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
new StreamSource(inputFileStream)
```

you should instantiate a `SAXSource`, containing an `XMLReader` initialized to use the catalog resolver as its `EntityResolver`.

If you need to do the same thing for other source documents, such as those read using `doc()` or `document()`, you should supply a `URIResolver` which itself returns a `SAXSource` initialized in the same way.

There are other ways of doing it using Saxon configuration properties, but I think the above is the simplest.